# Webclient + proxy

Tags: c#, winforms

Таким образом точно будет работать через прокси, а не мой IP ?

Боюсь свой подставить( - какой есть метод проверить ?

```
    WebProxy web = new WebProxy("прокси");
    web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("логин", "пароль");
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
```

Comment: нет, надо еще wc.Proxy задать. а ты не бойся, а поработай головой, 2ip.ru для кого придумали? я уж не говорю о том, что мог бы за 1 день разобраться как сайт на пыхе сделать, который будет говорить что за айпи у тебя

Comment: @koshkashoshka здорово, спасибо - мой вопрос решён строчкой
wc.Proxy = web;